# How to mirror text in Java

Tags: java, text, substring, joptionpane, mirroring

I'm trying to create a full diamond and I have almost all of it down

```
T T
Te  Te
Tes   Tes
Test    Test
Test   Tes
Tes  Te
Te T
T
```

These for loops are what create the diamonds, but the spaces.substring is where I am having difficulties. Would anyone know how to approach this by solely editing the spaces.substring?

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
    { 
        System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0,i));            
        System.out.print (word.substring (0,i) + System.lineSeparator()); 
        //System.out.print(SPACES.substring(i,i+1));
        System.out.print (word.substring (0,i+1));
    }  
    for (int g = len ; g >= 0; g--)
    {          
        System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0,g));           
        System.out.print (word.substring (0,g) + System.lineSeparator());              
        System.out.print (word.substring (0,g));            
    }
```

As you can see the first two lines in each for loop create the right half of the diamond, and the last lines creates the left half. But there is no spaces.substring for the left half, because I don't know what I would put in it.

Should look like this:

```
                                    H
                                   O O
                                  U   U
                                 S     S
                                E       E
                                 S     S
                                  U   U
                                   O O
                                    H
```

Comment: `System.out.print(something + System.lineSeparator())` --> `System.out.println(something)`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code

Are you allowed to use methods?

#### Yes:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Main().printDiamond("HOUSE");
}

private void printDiamond(String word)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        printPart(word, i);
    }

    for (int i = word.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printPart(word, i);
    }
}

private void printPart(String word, int i)
{
    space(word.length() - (i + 1));
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    if (i > 0)
    {
        space((i * 2) - 1);
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    space(word.length() - (i + 1));
    System.out.println();
}

private void space(int i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

#### No:

```
String word = "HOUSE";
String SPACES = "              ";
int len = word.length();

for (int i = 0 ; i < len; i++)
{
    System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0, len - (i + 1))); //print left padding spaces
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i)); //print left/middle character
    if (i > 0) //we don't want to do this on run 0 because there we only need to print one character in the middle (H)
    {
        System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0, (i * 2) - 1)); //print middle padding spaces
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i)); //print right character
    }
    System.out.println(SPACES.substring(0, len - (i + 1))); //optional: print right padding
}

for (int i = len - 2; i >= 0; i--) //start at len - 2. -1 because arrays start at 0 and -1 because we don't want to print the last character (E) again
{
    System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0, len - (i + 1)));
    System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    if (i > 0)
    {
        System.out.print(SPACES.substring(0, (i * 2) - 1));
        System.out.print(word.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(SPACES.substring(0, len - (i + 1)));
}
```

## Output

```
    H    
   O O   
  U   U  
 S     S 
E       E
 S     S 
  U   U  
   O O   
    H
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: Yea could you maybe explain what is going on in the non-method part. I'm confused with it

Comment: @JohnSmith I added some comments to the first for loop. In the second is basically the same